# Angular 2: HTTP call with URL Parameters

Tags: angular, typescript

I am a newbie to Angular. In my Angular 2 web application I am trying following to call backend service with URL parameters.

```
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http'
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  http: Http;
  constructor(http: Http) {
    console.log('Creating DataService');
    this.http = http;
  }

  getList(param1) {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('param1', param1);
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/test/getList', { search: params }).map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }

}
```

This gives a compile error in the Visual Studio Code console.

> Cannot find name 'URLSearchParams'

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

Issue solved by adding following import statement.

```
import {Http, Response, URLSearchParams} from 'angular2/http'
```